# Why is my Lottie animation loading properly on localhost server, but failing to load on the deployment server?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, next.js, lottie

So the problem is all the Lottie animations will load on my local host server, but once the web app is deployed the animation doesnt load and some error comes into the console. The animation files are .json file . My project is next js react project.

Link to lottie: `https://lottiefiles.com/`

But when i open my deployment server (which is vercel) the animation fails to load and there are some errors in the console. How do i fix this issue?

[image: Animation is loading in localhost server]

[image: Animation is loading in localhost server]

[image: This is my folder structure]

[image: This is how i have imported the animation json file]

[image: This is the error i am getting on the deployment server. The animation is not loading and it is throwing this error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying it on vercel there is some issue with that please check this github issue and comment https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/42801#issuecomment-1317671110, one solution suggest to disable swcMinify

```
// next.config.js

module.exports = {
  swcMinify: false,
}
```

Comment: Thank you balkishan, this solution works. 

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you pass your animationData, could you try JSON.stringifying it

```
JSON.stringify(animationData)
```

Comment: This is throwing this error: https://ibb.co/p0n13q5